# Meteor import error

Tags: meteor

I would like import a template for sending mail with email package with Meteor APP but I get the error `Can not found module email.html`. My relative path is correct.

My **/imports/startup/server/smtp.js**

```
import { email } from '../../ui/email/email.html';

// sendEmail function
```

This file, `smtp.js`, is imported on `/server/main.js`.

Do you have any idea why I have this error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are importa a html file, try use

import '../../ui/email/email.html';

Like view in oficial tutorial.